# Can you prevent invoices from being sent via Pay Later?

Tags: payment-processor, hooks, invoice

I'm setting up a Contribution Page to act as a sales desk at a silent auction. An operator will use the page to enter people's details and the payment that they made for any items, along with a textarea for recording item details.

In order to keep everything in the system, I have renamed "Pay Later" as "Cash Sale". Then afterwards we'll go through and mark all those items as Completed, which will e-mail through the receipts. (while it would be nice to avoid this step it's only a small inconvenience)

The only problem with this solution is that as soon as we use the Pay Later mechanism, an invoice is e-mailed through to the buyer. This is unnecessary and will be confusing.

Is there any way to prevent invoices from being sent when we use the Pay Now for a particular Contribution page? Any settings that I have missed, or even hooks?

Note that I'm not keen on doing the data entry in the back end (CiviCRM console) as the operator would have to create new Contact records for each person before the sale, and overall that would be far more work.

Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 1):

If the invoice generation is linked to specific financial types, then in that the case you could create a new financial type which isn't linked to automatic invoice generation.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent invoices from being sent automatically navigating to: Administer - CiviContribute - Component settings

```
URL: civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/contribute
```

At the bottom there's a checkbox which says: Automatically email invoice when user purchases online

The drawback is that you'll have to send them manually, which can be done form the Advanced search or find Contributions menu, in the Actions menu there should be a Print/Email invoices which allows you to do it in batch, it also applies for receipts.

Comment: The above option only shows if you have "Enable Tax and Invoicing" enabled

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Drupal you could make a Webform for the 'pay later' that links to a contribution page that is set to not send out receipt/invoices